# Gradle during building to WAR losts pictures data

Tags: maven, gradle, war

I've just migrated my app from **Maven** to **Gradle 2.5 (2.9 too)** *WAR* build tool and noticed that some resources like **jpeg, gif, bmp** lost their data - my computer is unable to read them or reads them but they're scratched. Do you know if this is connected to Gradle compression system and if yes, how to solve this?

Comment: It's rather not connected to gradle compression but the way gradle copies files to created war. Those files that can't be filtered should be copied separately. Are you doing any kind of filtering?

Comment: You were right - I have added `filesMatching('**/*.someFormat')`. You can add your answer - I will accept this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather not connected to **Gradle** compression but the way gradle copies files to created war. Those files that can't be filtered should be copied separately, or try exclude them using `filesMatching('**/*.someFormat')`

Comment: `filesMatching('**/*.someFormat')` necessary to exclude image extensions :)

Comment: @Rafcik, great. Feel free to edit the answer an add relevant content.